# Primefaces Reload an XHTML Page On Tab Change

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tabs

I am using a Primefaces Accordion component.  Each tab displays a `xhtml` page containing a `DataTable`.

I need to be able to refresh the page when the user selects the tab so that they can see changes to the Favorites list or the Contacts list.  Each list page has its own Managed Bean.

I am very new to JSF and PrimeFaces.  Would appreciate any help :)

```
<p:accordionPanel widgetVar="accordion">
    <p:tab title="My Favorites" id="myFavorites">
        <ui:insert name="favorites" >
            <ui:include src="/xhtml/favoritesList.xhtml" />
        </ui:insert>
    </p:tab>

    <p:tab title="My Contacts" id="myContacts">
        <ui:insert name="contacts" >
            <ui:include src="/xhtml/contactsList.xhtml" />
        </ui:insert>
    </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your first line by the following code which satisfies your requirement (uncached lazy loading).

```
<p:accordionPanel widgetVar="accordion" dynamic="true" cache="false">
```

Comment: probably saved my life

Comment: Glad it helped you.